# Making UIScrollView to both scroll and zoom

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am having some troubles making my `UIScrollView` to exhibit both scrolling and zooming. My class (which sub-classes `UIScrollView`) has a `UIView` as a sub-view, and in this sub-view I draw on a `CALayer`. As soon as the app launches, I can scroll the view, but as soon as I zoom using the pinch gesture, the scrolling feature stops working, and only the zoom works. My code:

```
bpmGraphView = [[UIView alloc] init];   
//--- configure the scroll-view and add the graph-view as a subview
[self setZoomScale:1.0];
[self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000.0, 169.0)];
[self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[self setScrollEnabled:YES];
self.maximumZoomScale = 20.0;
self.minimumZoomScale = 0.05;
self.clipsToBounds = YES;   
self.delegate = self;   //--- set the scroll-view delegate to self  
[self addSubview:bpmGraphView];
```

And the delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return [self bpmGraphView];
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Some dimensions: My `UIScrollView` is 320x169 and it is positioned 7 pixels to the right of the left edge of the screen. The (scrollable) `UIView` inside it should have the same height, but start 30 pixels to the left of the `UIScrollView`, and end somewhere far to the right - 1000 is just a test number. The sublayer I add to `UIView` should have the same size and position as it's superview.
I will init the `UIView` with the proper frame and report any changes in the behavior of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at a first look i just notice a big **ContentSize width** and a small **height**... are you sure you need it to be 1000 x (just) 169?

And which are the dimensions of bpmGraphView?

And why don't you **init** bpmGraphView with a dimension? It's a **UIView**, you should init it giving it a frame, with **initWithFrame:**, not just **init**.

And also: give us the dimension of your **UIScrollView**, the only dimension you give us is the **UIScrollView.contentSize**...

Comment: The reason I need a large width is that this view is holding an x-y kind of graph which grows only in the x direction, so I need to be able to plot more and more values along the x axis (while the corresponding y values are constrained to stay in a specific range). Regarding your other question, I will edit my question.

Comment: Ok, indeed the problem was that I had a large enough size for the sub-layer, so the graph was drown, but the `UIView` holding the layer had no size (since I did not changed it's frame, or used `initWithFrame`), so there was no view to scroll. Weird it did scroll at all until any zoom gesture...

Answer (score 1):

Refer this apple sample code, it contains everything about scrollview
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html